# Data not passing javascript jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am learning JavaScript. I would like to know why my code is not working?

```js
function test(data) {
  alert(data);
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript:test(data)">link </a>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0agwp694/

Comment: What data is there to pass?

Comment: example a string data as name

Comment: So make the valid example.  Don't make an invalid example

Comment: ***VM44:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined***

Comment: yes i get this error how to correct it ?

Comment: `data` is an undefined variable.  You cannot pass an undefined variable into a method

Comment: `<a href="javascript:test('data')" >link </a>`

Comment: Also you should avoid calling javascript from the href="" of a link.  Modern javascript attaches event handlers with `addEventListener`.

Comment: If you're learning jQuery then my tip would be: don't use `alert()` for debugging. Use `console.log()`, or better yet, research the `debugger` keyword and how to step through your code.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan r/jQuery/javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`href` is `hypertext reference`.Primarily `href` is not used to link a function. For that you can use  onclick & you need to use `event.preventDeafult`. Also you need to pass `data` as a string from the event handler

```js
function test(e, data) {
  e.preventDefault()
  alert(data);
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="test(event,'data')">link </a>
```

Check this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ljs6vk8z/) where href is used to call the function

Comment: From the `Javascript+No Library(pure JS)` dropdown select `load type bottom of the body`

Answer (score 0):

Check my comments below

```js
myData = [1,2,3]
function test(data) {
  alert(data);
}
```

```html
<!-- You cannot use data here, as data is a variable that is not defined at this point -->
<a href="javascript:test(data)">Not working</a><br>
<!-- Data here is a string -->
<a href="javascript:test('data')">Working</a><br>
<a href="javascript:test('any content you can think of')">Working</a><br>
<!-- myData is defined in the JavaScript outside of the function test and therefore you can use it -->
<a href="javascript:test(myData)">Working</a><br>
```

Comment: i tested not get alert ??

Comment: @SUPERMAN Is there any error message (Check the browser's development tools' console [F12]? What browser did you test on? Is anything happening at all?